# How do i make a button take text from an edittext and compare it to a random number?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make my button compare the number in the edit text to the random number I'm generating and make a toast if they're the same. the code runs but no matter what i set the bound to the number in the edit text never equals the random number.
Here is my code

```
    Button submit;
    EditText etcode;
    Random random = new Random();
    String generatedPassword = String.format(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(1)));
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);


        mFlower = findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        mDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        etcode = findViewById(R.id.et_code);
        Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (etcode.getText().toString().equals(generatedPassword)){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONGRATS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you aware, that you "generatedPassword" is always `0`?

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: i did that to see if it works. i thought it would be one -.- it works with 0

Comment: Well, just read the documentation of the `nextInt` method... Any more questions?

Comment: Just one more actually. is this a secure method of doing this? or rather could someone exploit this code to make the code always match?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this line

```
String generatedPassword = String.format(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(1)));
```

Because generatePassword is always 0 . That's why it works with zero.

```
random.nextInt(1);
```

Above code will always generate number less than 1.
You should change it to any other number.
Suppose you write`random.nextInt(5);`
Then above line will generate number between 0 to 5 means it can be 0,1,2,3,4.

Check this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-random-nextint-java/

Comment: You made a nice answer out of my comment (y)

Comment: Just kidding. Funny how this even got accepted, as it's just an explanation of the Random util, which has nothing to with the original question

Comment: I won't upvote a copy of my comment which already helped him lol. Also it won't help anyone who comes here and has trouble comparing EditText input with a random number